# Preastashop hookHeader displays in body instead in <head></head>

Tags: prestashop, hook, google-tag-manager

In my module I need to display Google Tag Manager code in between `<head></head>`. Following the information online I should use the hook "header" for it.

Unfortunately this hook displays content not between `<head></head>` but after `<body>`. Anyone has any idea why? Or how can I display content in `<head>`?

Comment: Did you check your theme template file `header.tpl`? You must have `{$HOOK_HEADER}` inside `<head></head>` in the template.

Comment: Thx, but yes I did. What I have understood from this, is that this hook is not for displaying things, you can only set the files (addJS, etc.) everything you want to echo or return is being printed in the body. Maybe this is why this hook is not called "displayHeader" but just header.  But then whole the internet is wrong, because you can find tons of "advices" that to print in <head></head> you have to use header hook, which is not true.